# jQuery selector help needed

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Here is my HTML fragment. I'm subscribing to "click" event of anchor "inquire". How do I traverse up to get `data-driverid` value?

```
<div class="DriverWrapper" data-driverid="108WW" style="background-color: Silver; padding: 4px 4px 4px 4px; page-break-before: always;">
    <strong>Driver ID:</strong>&nbsp;108WW
</div>

<table style="width: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 20%">
            <strong>174794</strong>&nbsp;
            <a href="#" class="inquireTripLink">inquire</a>
```

EDIT:

I tried this and it shows alert with `null`

```
$(".inquireTripLink").on("click", function (event) 
{
    event.preventDefault();

    var driverId = $(this).closest('.DriverWrapper').data('driverid');
    alert(driverId);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".inquireTripLink").on("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var driverId = $(this).closest('table').prev('.DriverWrapper').data('driverid');
    alert(driverId);
})
```

Your link appears to be in a table which isn't a child of the div, but a sibling.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/PZdPY/1)**

Comment: `closest` is a bit cleaner than `parents` and possibly a teeny tiny bit more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `closest` method.

```
$('.inquireTripLink').click(function(){
   var id = $(this).closest('.DriverWrapper').data('driverid');
});
```

**Update:** The `div` element is not parent of the clicked element, you have closed the `div` tag after `strong` tag. You can use `prev` method:

```
$('.inquireTripLink').click(function(){
   var id = $(this).closest('table').prev('div').data('driverid');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/J8cWT/

Comment: @katit You have closed the div tag here: `<strong>Driver ID:</strong>&nbsp;108WW</div>` is this intended?

Answer (score 0):

Try `$(this).closest("[data-driverid]").data("driverid")`

Comment: jQuery have some new `nearest` selector I haven't heard of? Perhaps you mean `closest()`?

Comment: That's what I get for trying to answer a jQuery question xD

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).closest("table").prev(".DriverWrapper").data("driverid");
```

It will break if you change your markup, but it works with your posted html.  You might consider adding a common parent and then doing the following instead:

```
$(this).closest("COMMON PARENT").find(".DriverWrapper").data("driverid");
```